# Having trouble in installing Pygame in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS!

Tags: 16.04, python-2.7

I want to install **Pygame** on my machine running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS(I already have **Python 2.7**). This is what it shows when I run `sudo apt-get install python-pygame` in 
the terminal :-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-pygame : Depends: python-numpy (>= 1:1.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: python-numpy-abi9
             Depends: libportmidi0 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libsdl-mixer1.2 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libsmpeg0 but it is not going to be installed
   ttf-mscorefonts-installer : Depends: cabextract
     E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages    (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: `You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these`                             
`E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages    (or specify a solution).`

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann it says this: 
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: ahhh. I forgot to add you need to be either `root` (thats why the error asks if you are) or use `sudo` to run this command as `root`: `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: in general one can say most commands used in ubuntu are trying to be helpful by telling you what might be the problem. and t herefore it is mostly a good choice to first read and try what the error message suggests.

Comment: my error message said this when I entered : sudo apt-get -f install pygame

Comment: It returns:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pygame

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48938/discussion-between-duvall912-and-phillip-zyan-k-lee-stockmann).